# How illustrate cells in attribute table?

Tags: polygon

I have an attribute table with 2883 rows which are the OA of Leicestershire with their Easting and Northing column. I have four more columns in the attribute table (four land use classes) that carry the population density of each land use class in each OA (i.e. 4*2883=11532 cells).

I want to create a polygon shapefile with 11532 polygons which every polygon's attribute is the population density mentioned in the original attribute table (it should be a table with 11532 rows and three columns of Easting, Northing and population density).

Does any one know how to sort this problem out?

Comment: Zeinab, could you mark your question with the kind of software you want to use to solve this problem otherwise it is hard to help you.

Comment: OA = Output Area > Example http://www.casa.ucl.ac.uk/googlemaps/OAC-super-EngScotWales.html

Comment: In general, it's a good idea to not include "hi" and "thanks" in the question, and to spend some time formatting the question it so that it's easier to read and contains all the details someone might need to help answer it.  Don't assume anything.

Comment: And/Or specify the format of the data - so we can figure out what software is suitable.

Answer (score 1):

Is the idea to convert points to polygons?  If you have ArcInfo, you could use the "Create Thiessen Polygons" tool.

Answer (score 0):

In QGIS, you could create a polygon grid and then join the point attributes to the polygon grid based on location.

Answer (score 0):

Or do you need to create spatial data from a non-spatial table?

The 2DPointReplacer and PointConnector transformers in FME/Data Interoperability Extension will do this quite simply.